# A mystery with dates....what are the chances?

Tags: probability

What are the chances that 5 dates, from 5 different years, in 5 different months, would all fall on the same day of the week. For back ground my daughter, my son, myself and my wife's birthdays all fall on the same day of the week. To throw another brick in the wall our wedding anniversary also meets this and falls on the same day of the week as all of our birthdays. The probabilities of this intrigue me but I am far from a mathematician. Please enjoy this rabbit hole of quandaries...lol

Comment: if you consider all five events completely independent, the probability is pretty small, about $0.00006$. But who knows, maybe you only wanted to marry a woman born on the same day of the week or picked a wedding day knowingly :)

Comment: If some of the dates are before $29$ February and some after, then this will not happen every year, which might affect the calculation of probability

Comment: WOW!!! This is fascinating. Did not expect responses so fast. Thank you all. Vasya, I definitely had to do a lot of research and find the perfect  woman with the right day of the week and we delayed our wedding by 4 years so it would match up...J/K Whats crazy is this also holds true with my Mom, her birthday matched all of ours as well in regards to the day of the week.

Comment: Dates are following (including Mom as another bonus date) 5/15/1953-07/15/1982- 09/23/1986- 6/10/2006- 3/18/2009- 4/29/2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This event is highly unlikely.  If we assume that all seven days are equally likely, then the probability is $$\frac{1}{7^4}=\frac{1}{2401}\approx 0.0004$$
or less than one-twentieth of one percent likelihood.

To calculate this, let the earliest of the five events be on an arbitrary day of the week.  Now, we need the other four events to be on precisely that day.  Each has probability $\frac{1}{7}$ of doing so, and we need this coincidence to happen four times.

---

Do keep in mind, however, that you might be suffering from [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) in witnessing this.  There are not only five important events in your life, so perhaps what happened is that out of thirty important events, five happened to fall on the same day of the week.  The probability of *this* coincidence is much much smaller.

Comment: Please check your decimal for $\frac{1}{7^4}$

Comment: @paw88789, thanks, fixed.

Comment: Very cool and I agree with the Selection Bias. Still a very good breakdown on your part. Thank you!